# How to write .then using std::future

Tags: c++11

I have a simple task class:

```
template<typename TType>
class YHMTask
{
public:
    YHMTask() {};
    template<typename TLambdaFun>
    auto then(TLambdaFun f) -> std::future<decltype(f(mTask.get()))>
    {
        std::move(mTask);
        return std::async(std::launch::async, f, mTask.get());
    }
    std::future<TType> mTask;
private:
};
```

In this code, .then can be used and return a std::future.

But I want .then to return another YHMTask so that I can call .then after .then.
I tried to change .then code to follow:

```
template<typename TLambdaFun>
auto then(TLambdaFun f) -> YHMTask<decltype(f())>
{
    std::move(mTask);
    std::async(std::launch::async, f, mTask.get());
    YHMTask<decltype(f())> yhmTask(std::move(this));
    return yhmTask;
}
```

And call .then like this:

```
auto testTask = YHMCreateTask(PostAsync(L"", L"")).then([=](wstring str)
{
    return 1;
});
```

Compilier give me this error:

```
error C2672: 'YHMTask<std::wstring>::then': no matching overloaded function found
error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'YHMTask<unknown-type> YHMTask<std::wstring>::then(TLambdaFun)'
```

How should I do?

Comment: Between this code and your question yesterday, I suspect that you need to get a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: I add some code that try to achieve this feature, but didn't work. Could you help me?

Comment: Curious if you took a look at the facebook library I mentioned in my answer?  Did it work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create `yhmTask` you are moving `this`, which is a pointer.  There is no constructor for `YHMTask` that takes a pointer to a `YHMTask` so the template specialization fails.  You should dereference `this` before moving it:

```
YHMTask<decltype(f())> yhmTask(std::move(*this));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are interested in extending std::future to have .then().  I recommend taking a look at [Futures for C++ at Facebook](https://code.facebook.com/posts/1661982097368498/futures-for-c-11-at-facebook/).  It does what your attempting to do and more.

Lets you chain a sequence tasks using then:

```
Future<double> fut =
  fooFuture(input)
  .then(futureA)
  .then(futureB)
  .then(futureC)
  .then(d)
  .then([](OutputD outputD) { // lambdas are ok too
    return outputD * M_PI;
  });
```

Also provides other [compositional building blocks](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/futures/README.md#compositional-building-blocks) such as collect, map, and reduce.  Git repo [here](https://github.com/facebook/folly/tree/master/folly/futures).  Looks like [C++17](https://paoloseverini.wordpress.com/2014/04/07/concurrency-in-c11/) may also have support for the .then construct.